# adding package to a vector of packages inside an object

Tags: c++, vector

So I have a Truck object that contains a vector that will hold packages. I am creating a `Letter` which is a subclass of package, and would like to add to it. When I try to use add a letter to the vector I get an error

This is my main class that has the letter initialized

main()

```
Letter *letter = new Letter();
trucks.packages.push_back(letter);
```

This is what it looks like inside the truck.h file

truck.h

`std::vector<Package> packages;` is initialized as public

The error I get is `no matching function for call to std::vector<Package>::push_back(Letter*&)’ truck.packages.push_back(letter);`

Comment: Please show us the code along with the error message.

Comment: what code do you want? the error is added to the question

Comment: Give us a minimal code example that reproduces the problem you're having.

Comment: @0x499602D2 fixed some stuff to make it a little bit better, if you need anything else please let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `push_back` a pointer `Letter*`, but the vector packages is defined as a container of `Package`, not `Package*`.

Define

```
std::vector<Package*> packages;
```

Best is to use smart pointers `std::shared_ptr<Package>` or `std::unique_ptr<Package>` instead of raw pointers, for example

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Package> > packages;
std::shared_ptr<Letter> letter(new Letter());
trucks.packages.push_back(letter);
```

This way, you won't have to do manual deallocation etc.

Comment: you could improve this with `std::make_shared`

Comment: @OMGtechy, yes, just saw actually Ox49...'s answer, totally agree (in case you don't need direct access to `letter` anymore, and probably you won't).

Comment: @vsoftco If I need to do some work with the actual object, calculate price and stuff, would I just make the object and then when I'm ready to add it then add it?

Comment: @kevorski not sure exactly how you're going to use it, but as long as the object is constructed and valid, you can later add it at anytime you want in the vector.

Answer (score 2):

Your vector is declared to take a `Package` object by value. Since `letter` is a *pointer* to a `Letter` object, the types won't match and thus your error. Change your vector's type to take `Letter*`:

```c++
std::vector<Package*> packages;
```

Futhermore it is recommended you use memory management containers so as to avoid memory leaks (like when forgetting to `delete` as it seems you've done) and to facilitate manual memory management. Such a container provided by the standard is `std::shared_ptr<>`:

```c++
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Package>> packages;
packages.push_back(std::make_shared<Package>());
```